# converting object to merged object as desired

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a object like below:

```
{
   departments[0]: "Pricing",
   departments[1]: "Technology",
   locations[0]: "Berlin",
}
```

I want to convert it to

```
{
    departments: "Pricing, Technology",
    locations: "Berlin"
}
```

Also it should retain the same if the object is already in desired state.

Any help would be appreciated. I am not able to put my head around this.

I am trying something like below:

```
let tempkey= '';
Object.keys(temp1).forEach(key => {
    if(key.indexOf('[') !== -1) {
        tempkey = // then do substring and remove last three characters
    }
  let value = temp1[key];

});
```

[image]

Comment: do you want a new object or the same object reference? please add your try.

Comment: I want new object.

Comment: Your first 'object' is no valid object at all. Instead of a key you're giving it an array reference.

Comment: @obscure Actually its how the url is parsed. I am using vue-router and that object is part of route parameters.

Comment: And this is exactly what you're getting back? Not simply two arrays?

Comment: There is one way where i get directly what i need. and from other page, when i link it, i get the above useless object due to some php way of making route. its bit complicated to explain :-(

Comment: If you try to log temp1 what's your result? Cause as @obscure said the key is not valid, so I can't understand how the returned object could be like the one you wrote.

Comment: Added image as a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the key and index part of the key and then get an array of the splitted value of the new property, assign the value and join the array to a new property.

```js
var object = { 'departments[0]': "Pricing", 'departments[1]': "Technology", 'locations[0]': "Berlin", "state": "York" },
    result = Object.entries(object).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
        var match = k.match(/([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/);
        if(match){
            var [key, index] = match.slice(1),
            temp = (o[key] || '').split(', ');          
            temp[index] = v;
            o[key] = temp.join(', ');            
            return o;
        } else {
            o[k] = v;
            return o;
        };
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. this solves my half of the issue. What if the object is already in desired condition?

Comment: you could take this object instead of the empty object as start value for `reduce`. please add an example.

Comment: I hope the last change could be useful :-). You were asking for this behaviour, am I right? @Pradeepb

Comment: Thank you @FedericoGalfione. I had done that by myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Here idea is

- Object entries to get key/value from object.
- Now use split on each key to get value upto first `[`
- Add value to `op` object based on key, if `op[key]` is empty we don't add `,` before value else we add `,` before value to get desired result.

```js
let obj = {
   'departments[0]': "Pricing",
   'departments[1]': "Technology",
   'locations[0]': "Berlin",
} 

let op = Object.entries(obj).reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  key = key.split('[',1)
  op[key] = op[key] || ''
  op[key] += op[key] ? `, ${value}` : value
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :-)